# Accessibility error with boost addable and dll

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2008, boost, dll

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, on Windows Vista, and converting functions to build as a Debug DLL.

### Compiler Errors:

I'm getting an accessibility error with boost::operator templates:

```
error C2248: 'Field::Integer::Integer' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Field::Integer'  
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_52_0\boost\operators.hpp(257) : while compiling class template member function 'Field::Integer boost::operator +(Field::Integer,const Field::Integer &)'
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_52_0\boost\operators.hpp(836) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::addable1<T,B>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Field::Integer,
1>            B=boost::detail::empty_base<Field::Integer>
1>        ]
1>        see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::addable<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Field::Integer
1>        ]
1>        see reference to class template instantiation Field::Numeric<Value_Type,Descendant_Class>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Value_Type=int,
1>            Descendant_Class=Field::Integer
1>        ]
```

### Code (reduced to essential statements):

```
#ifndef FIELD_INTEGER_HPP
#define FIELD_INTEGER_HPP

#ifdef FIELD_EXPORTS
#define FIELD_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FIELD_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "boost/operators.hpp"

namespace Field
{

template <class Value_Type, class FIELD_API Descendant_Class>
class FIELD_API Numeric
    : public boost::addable<Descendant_Class>,
      public boost::subtractable<Descendant_Class>,
      public boost::multipliable<Descendant_Class>,
      public boost::dividable<Descendant_Class>
{
  public:
                                Numeric(const Value_Type&   new_value = 0);
                                Numeric(const Numeric& fn);
    virtual                     ~Numeric();

    Descendant_Class            operator+=(const Descendant_Class& dc);
    Descendant_Class            operator-=(const Descendant_Class& dc);
    Descendant_Class            operator*=(const Descendant_Class& dc);
    Descendant_Class            operator/=(const Descendant_Class& dc);

    void                        clear_field(void);
    bool                        supports_value_as_string(void) const;
};


class FIELD_API Integer
    : public Field::Numeric<int, Field::Integer>
{
  public:
        //! Destructor
    virtual                     ~Integer();
  protected:
    //! Constructor
                                Integer(const int               new_value);

    //! Copy constructor
                                Integer(const Integer& fui);
};

} // End namespace Field

#endif  // FIELD_INTEGER_HPP
```

My objective is to make the above code into an exportable Debug DLL or a Release DLL.
The code builds with no errors in the static library settings.

### Question:

In the above code, what are the modifications necessary to make this into a Debug or Release DLL (Visual Studio 2008, Windows Vista, 32-bit)?

I searched the web and StackOverflow, and I only get results for using templates, not passing classes as template arguments and DLLs.

Comment: why are the `Field::Integer` constructors `protected`? You might want to change it to `public` or add a `friend class Numeric<int, Integer>` to the `Integer` class definition.

Comment: The constructors are `protected` because I don't want this as a leaf class.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why it compiles as a static library and not as a DLL, but a friend class declaration should resolve your error.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Which class(es) should be friends?

Comment: I formulated an answer, my friendship comment was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `Numeric` inherits from `boost::addable` (as well as 3 more related classes). This will generate a non-member function `operator+` of signature

```
Field::Integer boost::operator +(Field::Integer,const Field::Integer &)
```

The reason it takes its left argument by-value is to optimize for rvalue references and copy-elision. This requires access of `boost::operator+` to the copy constructor of `Integer`, which is `protected` and therefore you get an error. I don't understand why compiling as a static library does work for you, where a DLL does not.

For access problems like this, the recommended way is to make the copy constructor `public`. Not wanting `Integer` as a leaf class seems a design-error to me, because if that's really what you want, why do you still want to be able to use it for addition and other arithmetic operations?

An alternative is to grant friendship to `boost::operator+(Integer, Integer const&)`. The friendship route is not recommended because it is dependent on the implementation of `boost::addable`. Normally you would grant friendship to the class `boost::addable`, but the implementation of it will use a non-member friend function `operator+` rather than a member function `operator+`. You should not let  your own class `Integer` depend on such implementation details.